# Faster du/stat alternative for directories

Tags: linux, command-line, du, stat

I have several very big directories and i want to know their estimated size. I use for this purpose mostly `du`, but it takes for each folder about 3 minutes, so i'm asking if there is an alternative to `du` or `stat` that takes less time (it could be imprecise: ~10% would be ok)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question came up before quite [a few times](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+fast+du). As far as I know here are some possible alternatives:

- **Different filesystems** - If you can put each directory you're interested in on a filesystem of its own then you can just use `df` instead of `du` -> instantaneous.
- **Quotas** - If you can change ownership of the directories, then you can make each owned by a different user, setup disk quotas for them and use it to keep track of how much space they're using (instantaneous also).
- **cron** - Running `du` in a cron job (say every day or so) and using the result of the last job instead of running `du` directly. If you don't care about a little inaccuracy that might be an option.
- [JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/) reportedly can quickly analyse a drive or folder that has been recently analysed.
- [Filelight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filelight) or [Disk Usage Analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Usage_Analyzer) might be an option too. According to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/25466/fast-way-of-knowing-real-directory-size-on-linux-bsd):

  > If you've got a desktop environment on the box in question, FileLight is awesome. It's fairly quick and allows you to drill down a directory tree and then only rescan that sub-tree when you want to get an updated view. You could very well run a full scan once a day and then just leave the program open all day without ever doing an update.